# GAE - How to make an XML-RPC call?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xml-rpc

I need to make a standard XML-RPC call to the UPC Database (www.upcdatabase.com) using my Google AppEngine **Java** application.

I found a lot of information on incorporating XML-RPC within GAE but couldn't find anything on how to make a call **from** GAE.

Any help or examples would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what do you know....

I did the following using the [Redstone XMLRPC](http://xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/%20%22Redstone%20XMLRPC) library and it works. Won't have figured that with all the focus on using URLFetch.

```
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient("http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc", false);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("rpc_key", rpc_key);
    params.put("ean",upc);

    HashMap<?,?> token = null;
    try {
        token = (HashMap<?, ?>) client.invoke( "lookup", new Object[] { params } );
    } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlRpcFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Don't quite know why it works and would love an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article about how to do it: http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2008/08/25/making-xmlrpc-calls-from-a-google-app-engine-application/

EDIT: Sorry, I missed you were asking about Java specifically. The basic idea is the same in either language, though: make an UrlFetch request.

Here's another blog I found with some discussion: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/01/xmlrpc-with-gae-java.html -- this one uses HTTPBuilder because at the time it was written UrlFetch wouldn't allow setting the User-Agent. That's been fixed (see http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/04/sdk-version-121-released.html) though so implementing this should be much easier.

Comment: I went through that one... didn't really get anything from it.... I'm just making the XML manually and using the standard Java.NET POST through UrlFetch... the post seems to be going through fine but the XML is still a pain...